# Import my html mobile site to iOs and Android

Tags: android, html, ios

I have a website which I've stripped down and changed a little its CSS to look good on mobile.
I want it to have an application on the app store (iphone and android) but I dont wish to build an application for it. just want it to be the same html website without the address bar etc.

Like fetching it in php (file_Get_contents...) but on an application. I want it client side (its more popular today..)

I'm a php programmer but yet I have no knowledge of programming in android and iphone and I'm looking for a simple solution 'casue I dont wish to get too much invloved right now in building a complicated app.

Thanks in advanced, Tal

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create mobile application in HTML/CSS/JS with [PhoneGap Build](http://build.phonegap.com).

Comment: I do not wish to build it from scratch.. just to do something like an "iframe" to my existing website.

Comment: You can embeded a internal navigator but i'm not sure Apple validate your apps...
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser

Comment: Using PhoneGap, it should be fairly trivial to create an Android app that just opens a WebView that points to your site. As jlafforgue says, it's unlikely that an iOS app like this would be accepted by Apple in the app store.